# Javac issue, classpath not finding file inside folder, but it does outside folder

Tags: java

I am trying to compile a file with `javac`. It turns out that I can compile it in the current directory, using "." as follows.

This works:

```
  javac -cp "." Hello.java
```

But when I leave it inside a folder, it's not compiling. Example:

```
  javac -cp ".:/folder/" Hello.java
```

I've tried different combinations for the second block, but none of them has worked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: where is the file located? you have to know that the classpath is for finding other classes not this you are compiling

Comment: the file is inside a folder called "folder" and the folder is in the current directory. @chokdee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-cp` option designates the *classpath*, not the source code location! That is, the Java compiler will look for class files there, but you'll still need to tell the compiler exactly where your source files are, eg.:

```
javac folder/Hello.java
```

if your `Hello.java` is in `./folder`. If your `Hello` class depends on other classes, these should be present on the classpath:

```
javac -cp .:mylib:otherlibs folder/Hello.java
```

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks @Anders it's just that I want to compile using classpath since I am studying for ocjp and that's in the contents. Thanks for clarifying, regards.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the location.

```
javac -cp ".:/folder/" /folder/Hello.java
```